# sql connection through c++ xll

Tags: c++, sql, visual-studio-2008, excel-2007, xll

i am trying to write a xll in c++ to interact with sql server. 
 the program compiles okay. I have the following simple lines inside the c++ code

```
database.test(){
              ....
    sql::Driver *driver;
    sql::Connection *con;
    sql::Statement *stmt;
    sql::ResultSet *res;
    con = driver->connect("NJROS1LD120", "mysql","mysql01"); 
              ... }
```

now when i try to open up excel i get junk characters in excel cells and the first line says "This program cannot run in DOS mode".
If I comment out the line con = driver->connect("NJROS1LD120", "mysql","mysql01");
i can see the function database.test() in the addin.

Can't figure out what is going wrong. It would be very kind of someone to help.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You are pretty far from home. Check out http://xll.codeplex.com. At least it will let you create an addin without the dreaded DOS mode error. Are you trying to connect to a MySQL database using an ODBC driver?

Answer (score 0):

You are most likely missing dlls. Use dependency walker to figure out what dlls are missing. I'm assuming you're using the mysql cpp connector so you would want to make sure that libmysql.dll and mysqlcppconn.dll can both be found.